# Print website with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, html, printing, tabs

Within a website I'm developing there're several info tabs, each of them displaying different reports or graphs when activated.

But when trying to print the website with `window.print()` it only prints the current displayed tab, that's the current website status, applying the printable CSS styles.

My customer wants to print the whole information in the website, but with the less user interaction as possible. That means without moving from one tab to another, clicking on "print" button for every single page, and avoiding the "validate" and "accept" printing process.

To sum up, my customer wants a single "print" button that prints every single document contained in the different tabs. I am afraid this is 100% impossible as is planned.

May I have to create a printing pool background process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that with CSS only. Just use `@media print { }`. If your tabs are hidden with `display: none;` you can just use

```
@media print {
    .tabs {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do a custom print css

```
@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

You can then have all content tabs  displayed as display:block